# Trying to launch a Ubuntu 18.04 on a instance-store in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I'm trying to launch a Ubuntu 18.04 with a `instance-stored` device type on AWS. I search for Ubuntu 18.04 and find this one (`ami-02e8efe84b4da2817`):

[image]

Okay, then I select the simplest instance type available, `m5d.large`:

[image]

... but when I launch the instance, I get the following error:

> Launch Failed 
>   AMI 'ami-02e8efe84b4da2817' with an instance-store root
>   device is not supported for the instance type 'm5d.large'.

Why do I get this error if I followed all the launching steps? What do I have to do to run a Ubuntu 18.04 on a `instance-stored`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do this specifically, out of interest.

Comment: Too tricky to explain it in 600 characters, sorry. But I need what stated in the post, `Ubuntu 18.04` with `instance-store`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I raised the question to the Amazon Support team and they stated me that, currently, `M5D` instance type do not support instance store volume to be a root volume. Though `M5D` instance comes with an `NVME instance store`, the root volume of the instance must be an Amazon `EBS` volume.

So I asked why I was able to select it on the panel and they told me it's a bug and they reported it internally.

The solutions are:

- Use `X1` or `D2` instance types, which are much powerful and more expensive.
- Use a `EBS` (root volume) and `instance-store` (data volume).